# Simple ASCII Gantt

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

This is a simple one: print an ASCII [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart).

Given tasks' ranges (start-time - end-time Tuples), print a Gantt timeline in the form of `-` characters for each task duration - each task in a new line.

#### Example

Say my tasks ranges are `28->35, 34->40, 39->44`, the Gantt will look like this:

```
                            -------
                                  ------
                                       -----
```

#### Specifications

- You can write a full program, a named function or an anonymous function.
- Your program/function should accept the tasks via STDIN **or as arguments**.
- Each task should be represented as a string of `start->end` where `start` and `end` are **Integers**. Tasks are separated by spaces or commas. **Alternatively**, you may get it as a Tuple of Integers, or as an Array/Collection of 2 Integers. (For example, in JavaScript you can get it as `[start,end]` - this is allowed).
- Any non-negative number of tasks (arguments) should be supported.
- <strike>To make it clear, a single argument of tasks collection is not allowed. You can either parse a single string argument, or support zero-or-more tasks arguments. Where task is a tuple or a collection of size 2.</strike>
- You can assume only valid input will be given. That means, each task has a positive duration.
- Return value does not matter, your code must print the timeline on STDOUT.
- Output: per task, `start` spaces followed by `(end-start)` dashes and a `\n`.
- Needless to say, output lines should be ordered correspondingly with the input (tasks) order.
- Trailing spaces before the `\n` are allowed, if that helps you.

#### Test cases

```
Input:
(empty)

Output:
(empty)


Input:
0->7,5->6,3->6

Output:
-------
     -
   ---


Input:
5->20,5->20,2->10,15->19

Output:
     ---------------
     ---------------
  --------
               ----
```

#### Winning

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the least code length (in bytes) wins.
- Traditionally, tie breaker is earlier post.
- "Standard loopholes are no longer funny".

### -----

### EDIT

As many of you understood that it is allowed to have a single tasks collection argument, and since there's no much different between that and the original [varargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) requirement,
**it is now allowed to have a single collection argument, if you don't want to use the varargs option, or in case your language does not support varargs.**

Comment: Point 3 seems clear. But piint 5 (`To make it clear...`) is not clear at all.

Comment: Alright, let me rephrase that: You cannot write a function that accepts exactly one argument unless it's a string. If it's a bunch of tuples we're talking about, they may be sent to your function as arguments, not wrapped in a collection. For example, in JavaScript: You may iterate `arguments` within the function, but you may not assume that `arguments[0]` is an array of tasks.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this limitation. In many languages accepting a list _is_ the way you create a function with a variable number of arguments. There is often no equivalent to Javascript's `arguments` list available.

Comment: There is no hidden purpose or reason behind it. I happen to like the "varargs" coding style. I'm sorry that your language does not support it - but  not all golfing challenges are suitable for all languages! You can still choose the string parsing option if you insist on a language that does not support varargs. I don't think it will be fair to allow it on some languages and not on others.

Comment: Why not simply allow input as an array / list / vector / etc. for all languages? Personal preference seems like a pretty weak reason.

Comment: Varargs versus an argument list is a purely syntactic distinction and leaves the rules of this question up to an unnecessary and arbitrary degree of interpretation, in my opinion.

Comment: Fine. I will edit now the question to allow it.

Comment: Is is acceptable to use MySQL with a table containing the data?

Comment: I'm not sure. You may use SQL / T-SQL and define a `FUNCTION` or a `PROCEDURE`.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do. but I'm not sure if those SQL 'flavors' have arrays or not. And how that works.

Comment: As far as I know, a Table-Typed Parameter is the Array equivalence in SQL :) However, please consume the table as a Procedure's input parameter, do not count on existing table in a database. You can state in your answer something like: Usage `DECLARE @G TABLE(x INT, y INT); INSERT INTO @G VALUES( ... )` and then `EXEC` your procedure on `@G`.

Comment: I'm not having luck in any way. But thanks a lot for the help. I hope it is useful to someone else.

Comment: Given that: 1)you can accept whenever you like,2)14 bytes seems impossible to beat, 3)anyway you can change your mind later ... Givel all this, It seems too early accepting an asnwer just 1 day after the question. It gives the message: ok, the challenge is over, go think about somthing else ....

Comment: May we take two list arguments; all the start-times and all the end-times?

Comment: I’m sorry @Adám but the answer is no. It won’t be fair for existing answers.

Comment: @Jacob Makes sense. For future challenges, I'd recommend as lax an input spec as possible: Mangling input shouldn't be part of the challenge.

Comment: Can we take a 1-indexed input? ie `29->36, 35->41, 40->45` in place of  `28->35, 34->40, 39->44`

Comment: May there be zero-duration tasks? This should be mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## CJam, <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
q~{S.*~'-e]N}/
```

This expects a list of lists as input. For example:

```
[[5 20] [5 20] [2 10] [5 19]]
```

gives:

```
     ---------------
     ---------------
  --------
     --------------
```

**How it works**

```
q~                      e# Read the input and parse it as a list of list
  {         }/          e# Go over each item in the list in a for loop
   S                    e# S is basically this string - " "
    .*                  e# Multiply each item of the first list with the corresponding index
                        e# item of the second list. This basically repeats the space
                        e# X times where X is the first number of the tuple. The second
                        e# number remains untouched as the second list was only 1 char long
      ~                 e# Unwrap the space string and second number containing list
       '-               e# Put character '-' on stack
         e]             e# Make sure that the space is filled with - to its right so as to
                        e# make the total length of the string equal to the second number
           N            e# Put a newline. After all iterations, the result is printed
                        e# automatically to STDOUT
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7E%7BS.*%7E%27-e%5DN%7D%2F&input=%5B%5B5%2020%5D%20%5B5%2020%5D%20%5B2%2010%5D%20%5B5%2019%5D%5D)

Answer (score 20):

## Python 2, 39 Bytes

Straightforward solution using string multiplication :)

```python
for x,y in input():print' '*x+'-'*(y-x)
```

Accepts input formatted like so:

```python
((5,20),(5,20),(2,10),(15,19))
```

[Check it out here.](http://ideone.com/hPZ0bv)

Answer (score 12):

### Brainfuck, <s>120</s> <s>115</s> 111 bytes

At least it's shorter than Java :) The input is a list of bytes, where each pair is a single line in the gantt.

```
++++[->++++++++<]>[->+>+<<]++++++++++>>+++++++++++++>+[,[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>],<[->-<<<<.>>>]>[-<<<.>>>]<<<<<.>>>]
```

**Try out**

http://copy.sh/brainfuck/

Set end-of-input to <kbd>char</kbd> with value `\0`. Example input:     `\5\20\5\20\2\10\15\19`.

*Note that setting the end-of-input value to `\0` will have the side effect that no more input will be read (and thus stopping the program) when the input contains the number zero. In BF there is no other way of knowing when the input is exhausted.*

**Explanation***

```
++++[->++++++++<]>  #Store <space> at index 1                   
[->+>+<<]           #Move index 1 to index 2 and 3
++++++++++          #Increment index 1 to <newline>
>>                  #Move to index 3
+++++++++++++       #Increment index 3 to <dash>    
>                   #Move to (empty) index 4
+                   #Increment to start the main loop
[                   #Main loop
,                   #Read first number to index 4
[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>] #Copy index 4 to index 5 (index 5 can now be altered)
,                   #Read second number (the number pair is now stored at index 5 and 6)
<                   #Move to first number (index 5)
[->-<<<<.>>>]       #Decrement index 5 and 6 and print <space> until index 5 equals zero
>                   #move to second input (index 6)
[-<<<.>>>]          #Decrement index 6 and print <dash> until index 6 equals zero
<<<<<.>>>           #Print <newline> and move to index 4 (original first number)
]                   #End of main loop
```

*<sub>*(You won't be able to compile/run this due to the comments)</sub>*

Comment: Brainfuck shorter than Java => world will soon end.

Comment: The explanation should actually run fine. The only bf commands in there are `<` and `>`, and they're perfectly balanced.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Nice catch, I did not even try to see if they were balanced ;)

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, <s>36</s> <s>22</s> <s>19</s> 14 bytes

This is my first Pyth program. Jakube helped golf out 5 bytes!

```
FNQ<s*V" -"NeN
```

It expects input in the form `[[5,20], [5,20], [2,10], [15,19]]`.

You can [try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=FNQ%3Cs*V%22+-%22NeN&input=%5B%5B5%2C20%5D%2C+%5B5%2C20%5D%2C+%5B2%2C10%5D%2C+%5B15%2C19%5D%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 5):

## C++14, 69 bytes

```c
[]{int a,b;for(;cin>>a>>b;){cout<<setw(b)<<string(b-a,'-')+'\n';}}();
```

First time golfing, this was a good problem to start with!

Comment: Don't you need `std::` on `cin` and `cout`?

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, <s>67</s> <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```
(r:Seq[(Int,Int)])⇒for((s,e)←r)(println(" "*s+"-"*(e-s)))
```

Usage:
    `res0()` or `res0(Seq(28->35, 34->40, 39->44))` etc.

Thanks gilad for shaving 4 bytes using a for expression!

Answer (score 3):

## K, 18 bytes

```
`0:" -"@{&x,y-x}.'
```

Expects a list of pairs as input:

```
  `0:" -"@{&x,y-x}.'(0 7;5 6;3 6)
-------
     -
   ---
  `0:" -"@{&x,y-x}.'(5 20;5 20;2 10; 15 19)
     ---------------
     ---------------
  --------
               ----
  `0:" -"@{&x,y-x}.'()
```

I unpack each (`'`) tuple using dot-apply (`.`) so that inside the lambda I have access to the start and end value as `x` and `y`, respectively. Then I reassemble these into a (start,length) tuple (`x,y-x`) and apply "where" (`&`). This gives me output like so:

```
  {&x,y-x}.'(0 7;5 6;3 6)
(1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 1 1 1)
```

Then I simply have to index into a 2-character array using this ragged matrix (`" -"@`) and send it all to stdout (`0:`).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (*ES6*), 63

*Edit* 3 byte saved thx @apsillers
63 bytes not counting the assignment to F as an anonymous function is allowed.

<s>A function with a variable number of parameters, as requested.</s>
A function with a list of tasks as a single parameter.

Test running the snippet below (being EcmaScript 6, Firefox only)

```js
F=l=>l.map(t=>console.log(' '.repeat(l=t[0])+'-'.repeat(t[1]-l)))

// TEST

// for this test, redefine console.log to have output inside the snippet
console.log = (...x) => O.innerHTML += x + '\n';

console.log('* Empty'); F([]);
console.log('\n* [0,7],[5,6],[3,6]'); F([[0,7],[5,6],[3,6]])
console.log('\n* [5,20],[5,20],[2,10],[15,19]');F([[5,20],[5,20],[2,10],[15,19]]);
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Save one byte by assigning `t[0]` to a global (or you can safely assign it to `l` if you don't want to make a global). Also, the spec allows "a named function or an anonymous function" so I think you could omit the `F=` in your byte count.

Comment: @apsillers I missed the `anonymous` think. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby: 35 characters

```ruby
->*t{t.map{|s,e|puts' '*s+?-*(e-s)}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->*t{t.map{|s,e|puts' '*s+?-*(e-s)}}.call [0,7], [5,6], [3,6]
-------
     -
   ---
```

Updated to accept multiple two-element arrays, one for each task to display. (I think that is what the updated requirement expects.)

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript(ES6), 61/66 chars**

My answer is almost similar to the one posted by @edc65 , but with some improvements.
As tasks in single array are not allowed(so function would be called like this: `a([3,4], [7,15], [0,14], [10, 15])`), correct one would be this(**66 chars** without name assignment):

```
a=(...x)=>x.map(([c,d])=>console.log(' '.repeat(c)+'-'.repeat(d-c)))
```

And if one array argument is allowed(so fn call like this: `a([[3,4], [7,15], [0,14], [10, 15]])`), then it would be(**61 char** without assignment):

```
a=x=>x.map(([c,d])=>console.log(' '.repeat(c)+'-'.repeat(d-c)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
↑('-'\⍨≤∘⍳)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEdtEzXUddVjHvWueNS55FHHjEe9mzX1wXITNYwsFIxNNTWMTRRMDICUpYKJiSaXFleagoGC0aPeLQYgNkidgYK5poapghlQDZCAiZoqGBloQkkjBUMgaWiqYGipCQA)

APL has no varargs, so the arg here is a single Nx2 matrix.

Comment: If you can take two arguments (starts and ends) then `↑'-'\⍨¨≤∘⍳¨`

Comment: challenge author [says no](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52400/simple-ascii-gantt/154280?noredirect=1#comment376634_52400)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>280</s> <s>275</s> <s>246</s> <s>204</s> <s>195</s> <s>185</s> 180 bytes

```
void g(String t){for(String s:t.split(",")){String[]a=s.split("->");s="";Integer i;for(i=0;i<i.valueOf(a[0]);i++)s+=" ";for(;i<i.valueOf(a[1]);i++)s+="-";System.out.println(s);};};
```

A method that takes a comma-seperated input string and prints the resulting ascii Gantt Chart to stdout.

Thanks to durron597 and masterX244 for helping me save 10 bytes

Comment: I think you're allowed to use a method instead.

Comment: It is allowed iff this is the (or a) way to create an anonymous function in Java8. Is it?

Comment: It's the closest thing Java 8 has to such a feature.

Comment: If you do `Integer i=0;` you can do `for(;i<i.parseInt;`, saving 8 characters.

Comment: I couldn't get it to compile on Ideone, but it appears that it would not accept empty input, as the rules require (`t.split(",")` would throw an exception).

Comment: @Nateowami: This isn't a full program.

Comment: I realize that, and added boilerplate code. It said something about a missing symbol. Not saying it doesn't compile, just that I failed to.

Comment: @durron i.valueOf() is a bit shorter since Java converts the resulting Integer automatically to int without any code needed (autounboxing greets)

Answer (score 1):

## SWI-Prolog, 55 bytes

```
a([[A,B]|C]):-tab(A),writef("%r",[-,B-A]),nl,C=[];a(C).
```

Example: `a([[5,20],[5,20],[2,10],[15,19]]).` outputs

```
     ---------------
     ---------------
  --------
               ----
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the input format in this answer does not meet specifications - each task should be represented in one argument, not in two. (Unless I missed something in SWI-Prolog syntax which I'm not familiar with...)

Comment: @Jacob Yeah when rereading your post I figured that and already changed my code to account for it.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 44 bytes

```matlab
x->for t=x a,b=t;println(" "^a*"-"^(b-a))end
```

This creates an anonymous function that accepts an array of tuples as input and prints to STDOUT.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
function f(x)
    # Loop over the tasks (tuples) in x
    for t in x
        # Assign a and b to the two elements of t
        a,b = t

        # Print a spaces followed by b-a dashes on a line
        println(" "^a * "-"^(b-a))
    end
end
```

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f([(5,20), (5,20), (2,10), (15,19)])
     ---------------
     ---------------
  --------
               ----

julia> f([(0,7), (5,6), (3,6)])
-------
     -
   ---

julia> f([])
```

Comment: Sure. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Jacob: No inconvenience. Nice challenge. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl: <s>42</s> 41 characters

Just to have at least one solution with string parsing too.

```perl
s!(\d+)->(\d+),?!$"x$1."-"x($2-$1).$/!ge
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ perl -pe 's!(\d+)->(\d+),?!$"x$1."-"x($2-$1).$/!ge' <<< '0->7,5->6,3->6'
-------
     -
   ---
```

Comment: Actually we already have the straightforward Java answer that parse a string :) Anyway, thanks for this one as well!

Comment: Yes, but as I understand that expects comma separated numbers, not the format specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>106</s> <s>85</s> <s>80</s> 68 bytes

As per the updated requirements, a list of tasks is now acceptable

```js
a=>a.reduce((p,v)=>p+=' '.repeat(z=v[0])+'-'.repeat(v[1]-z)+"\n",'')
```

Takes zero or more arguments: **80 bytes**

```js
(...a)=>{s='';a.map(v=>s+=' '[r='repeat'](z=v[0])+'-'[r](v[1]-z)+"\n");return s}
```

---

Original attempt, 106 bytes:

```js
(...a)=>{for(i=-1,s='',r='repeat';a.length>++i;){s+=' '[r](a[i][0])+'-'[r](a[i][1]-a[i][0])+"\n"}return s}
```

Comment: If it's ES6, then why not [`String.repeat()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.repeat)?

Comment: @manatwork Thanks for showing me something new!! Unfortunately for code golf it is actually longer to use that

Comment: Indeed, that two dimensional `a` not really helps. I had in mind something like `()=>{for(i=0,s='';a=arguments[i++];)s+='_'.repeat(a[0])+'-'.repeat(a[1]-a[0])+"\n";return s}`.

Comment: r='repeat' ? ... for 2 times? nah! `a=>a.reduce((p,v)=>p+=' '.repeat(z=v[0])+'-'.repeat(v[1]-z)+"\n",'')`

Comment: There is no output. `Return value does not matter, your code must print the timeline on STDOUT.` (and would be shorter too)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 76 bytes

```
(#)=replicate
f i=putStr$g=<<(read$'[':i++"]")
g(s,e)=s#' '++(e-s)#'-'++"\n"
```

Input format is a string of comma separated tuples, e.g. `"(1,2),(3,4)"`.

Usage examples:

```
*Main> f "(1,2),(3,4)" 
  -
    -

*Main> f "(0,7),(5,6),(3,6)" 
-------
     -
   ---
```

How it works: for input parsing I enclose the input string in `[` and `]` and use Haskell's native `read` function for lists of integer tuples. The rest is easy: for each tuple `(s,e)` take `s` spaces followed by `e-s` dashes followed by a newline and concatenate all into a single string. Print.

## Haskell, 59 bytes

with relaxed input format:

```
(#)=replicate
f=putStr.(g=<<)
g(s,e)=s#' '++(e-s)#'-'++"\n"
```

Now it takes a list of tuples, e.g `f [(0,7),(5,6),(3,6)]`.

Works as described above, but without input parsing.

Answer (score 1):

### C: 108 bytes

```
void g(int*l){for(int c=0;*l>=0;c=!c,l++){if(!c)l[1]-=*l;while(l[0]-->0)putchar(c?45:32);c?putchar(10):0;}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
void gantt(int*l) {
    for (int c = 0; *l >= 0; c = !c, l++) {
        if (!c) l[1] -= *l;
        while (l[0]-- > 0) putchar(c? 45 : 32);
        c? putchar(10) : 0;
    }
}
```

Takes as a parameter a list of integers terminated by `-1`. For example:

```
int list[] = {
    28, 35,
    34, 40,
    39, 44,
    -1
};
gantt(list);
```

It uses `c` to toggle between writing spaces and dashes.

Comment: Make c static - you can drop its type (it will be int) and initialization (it will be zero). `*l>=0` is the same as `*l+1` which is shorter. `c&&putchar` is shorter than ternary. If you replace `c=!c` with `c^=13` (+1 byte) you can change `c?45:32` to `32+c` (-3 bytes). Move `c` flip from `for` to the end of loop: `(c^=13)||putchar(10);`. `c;void g(int*l){for(;*l+1;l++){l[1]-=c?0:*l;while(l[0]--)putchar(32+c);(c^=13)||putchar(10);}}` - 94 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <strike>187</strike> <strike>181</strike> <strike>197</strike> <strike>183</strike> 101 bytes

```
void g(int[][]g){for(int[]i:g)for(int j=0;j<i[1];System.out.print(j++<i[0]?" ":j==i[1]?"-\n":"-"));}
```

Ungolfed (sort of):

```
void g(int[][] g){
    for(int[] i : g)
        for(int j = 0; j < i[1]; System.out.print(j++ < i[0] ? " " : j == i[1] ? "-\n" : "-"));
}
```

Accepts input as 2d array of `int`s. Thanks to [masterX244](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10801/masterx244) for pointing out that this is allowed by the rules.

Comment: you can shorten the loops if you use the 3rd bulletpoint of the current question version and varargs for the input

Comment: @masterX244 Thanks, I missed that. Seems to me like cheating to have it pre-parsed, but if cheating is allowed... whatever. I'll update it when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>13</strike> 9 bytes

```
ạ\⁾ -xµ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroUxjxr3KehWHNr6qGlN5P///6OjTXUUjAxidRQQDCMdBUMwwxAoZGgZGwsA)

Takes input as `[[5, 20], [5, 20], [2, 10], [15, 19]]`.

-4 bytes thanks to Erik

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroUxjxr3KehWHNr6qGlN5P///6OjTXUUjAxidRQQDCMdBUMwwxAoZGgZGwsA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES8), 54 bytes

```
a=>a.map(([x,y])=>"-".repeat(y-x).padStart(y)).join`
`
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NcexCoMwEADQvZ/hdAeXoxEcOsSf6BgCHhqLYpMQg@jXp@3Q6fFWOWQf85KKCnHydTZVTC/8lgRgT7ocmr5RDWefvBS41ImcZHoWyd8h8hqXMNyGOsawx83zFl8wg7UdtXdHf1rSP3RH@uEcYv0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 13 bytes

```
{" -"@&-':x}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlpJQVfJQU1X3aqiVv1/iVW1SnRlXZFVmkKFdUJ@trVGQlpiZo51hXWldZFmbC1XSbSBso6igbWGZiyQrWGgYG5tqmBmbaxgpsmloKChpAsBSkCOgpICCCDYIHGINlMFIwNrMGGkYGhgbWiqYGgJ0Q/RggqQDcMug0UlAuhC7P0PAA)

`{` `}` function with argument `x`

`{` `}'` apply to each - in this case to each pair of numbers from the input

`-':` subtract each prior - transform `(a;b)` into `(a;b-a)`

`&` "where" - transform `(a;b-a)` into a list of `a` zeroes followed by `b-a` ones

`" -"@` use as indices in `" -"`

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>117 90</s> 75 bytes

```r
function(y)for(i in 1:ncol(y))cat(" "<y[1,i],"-"<diff(y)[i],"
")
"<"=strrep
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYlBCsIwEADPzSvCnnZhCybQg5L@wlvxUKILC5pIjJC@PlbB0zAzpcvc5Z1i1ZxwI8kF1Wqy7pRivu@F4loRLIRtcawXhhHCVUX2tXzVABkIML9qKbdnbzaMtuJjrUUbRpzYH9gMw5@e3Y9uYnckZs9nIiPYqH8A)

Giuseppe golfed at least 29 bytes off my original answer!

The idea is straightforward: print as many `" "` as necessary followed by as many `"-"` as required. Input  is a `2*L` matrix with L the number of pairs. The vectorized function `diff` is used to get the number of "-".

Comment: @Giuseppe this is what I get for trying to trying to stick to my original `matrix` idea while using a `for` loop... ty!

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcqxCoNADIDhWZ8ipEuCERrBoaW@RTdxEOtBhp5yXun59NdW6PTDxx@y67J7@Sna4mlntwQyMA969WF5f4WnMVKYV0JA2XsTHSplOaRGeZhzFH9fbwMLlijbvHaInBPcaniOMViiiVppzlIWxb@N6FFtRS8s0sid4QSVlo4S5w8)

Comment: @Giuseppe Transposed `y` to save a few more :)

Comment: Now 1- indexed would [save 4](https://tio.run/##NYlBCsIwEADPzSvCnnbrFkygB8X8wlvxUGIXApqUGCF9fayCp2FmchPX5B19CSniRpIyBh2iNufo02Mv5OeCoKHfJsPhxjBAfw8i@5q@qoBfy@oASEEPLi9rq/oy6ILPueRQ0ePI9siq6/60bH40I5sTMVu@EumDUYKV2gc)

Comment: Nice, use `<` instead of `*` and you can get this to [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##NclBCsMgEEDRdTyFzGqGTqAKWbToLboLWQQbYaA1wVgwp7eh0NWD/3OLvsVPCkXWhAfFNaNoSdrcU1hfZ6EwFwQN7hgNy3QxDD24p8R4zlEmBgW8L5sHIAUOfF62VrXrdcH3XLJUDDiwvbLqur@WzU8zsLkRs@UHkYpYqX0B)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 3.0, <del>48</del>36 Bytes

```
$args|%{" "*$_[0]+"-"*($_[1]-$_[0])}
```

Thanks to Mazzy for saving 12 with a better way to pass in the list

Old code and explanation:

```
&{param($b="")$b|%{" "*$_[0]+"-"*($_[1]-$_[0])}}
```

Takes arguments as a list of tuples, e.g. (5,20),(5,20),(2,10),(15,19). Had to default $b to a value to take care of the empty string because it somehow entered the foreach block when called with no input.

Comment: 36 bytes: `$args|%{" "*$_[0]+"-"*($_[1]-$_[0])}`. Save as `get-asciiGantt.ps1`. Test script `.\get-asciiGantt.ps1 (5,20) (5,20) (2,10) (15,19)`

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), <s>99</s> 90 bytes

Using Immediate Window and `[A1]` as input eg.`0-1,2-5`

Thanks to @TaylorSott for cutting some bytes.

```
b=Split([A1]):For x=0To Ubound(b):c=Split(b(x),"-"):?Spc(c(0)-0)String(c(1)-c(0),"-"):Next
```

Comment: If you change the input format to being space delimited rather than being comma delimited, you cang chage the first two clauses from `a=[A1]:b=Split(a,",")` to `b=Split([A1])`. Also, you can drop the space before the `To` in the `For`  loop declaration.

Comment: Thanks and noted! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 9 bytes

```
ƛ÷ε\-*nt↳
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C6%9B%C3%B7%CE%B5%5C-*nt%E2%86%B3&inputs=%5B%20%5B0%2C7%5D%20%2C%20%5B5%2C6%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C6%5D%20%5D&header=&footer=) Expects a list of lists.

```
ƛ         # Map each pair to...
 ÷ε       # Their difference
   \-*    # -s
      nt↳ # Padded to the length of the second.
```

Answer (score 0):

### CoffeeScript, <s>104</s> 82, 65 bytes

List of tasks (ES6): **65 bytes**

```coffee
(a)->a.map (v)->console.log ' '.repeat(v[0])+'-'.repeat v[1]-v[0]
```

List of tasks (ES5 variant): **82 bytes**

```coffee
(a)->a.map (v)->j=-1;s='';s+=(if j<v[0]then' 'else'-') while++j<v[1];console.log s
```

Zero or more arguments: **104 bytes**

```coffee
()->[].slice.call(arguments).map((v)->j=-1;s='';s+=(if j<v[0]then' 'else'-')while++j<v[1];console.log s)
```

Unminified:

```coffee
() -> [].slice.call(arguments).map( # convert to array-like arguments to array and loop
 (v) ->
  j = -1 # counter
  s = '' # initialize string
  s += (if j < v[0] then ' ' else '-') while ++j < v[1]
  console.log s # print to STDOUT
)
```

Comment: Not sure from where to where is the JavaScript, CoffeeScript and ECMAScript in your answers, but in ECMAScript you can use `Array.from(arguments)` instead of `[].slice.call(arguments)`.

Comment: @manatwork As you can see in my answers (both ES5 and ES6, in CoffeeScript) addressing the changed requirement allowing a list of tasks, I don't need to reference `arguments` any more.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <s>94</s> 91 bytes

Takes a list of tasks (e.g. `[[5,20],[5,20],[2,10],[15,19]]`). Thanks @IsmaelMiguel for the reminder of variable function names.

```php
function x($a){$r=str_repeat;foreach($a as$v){echo$r(' ',$v[0]).$r('-',$v[1]-$v[0])."\n";}}
```

---

Original attempt: 94 bytes

```php
function x($a){foreach($a as$v){echo str_repeat(' ',$v[0]).str_repeat('-',$v[1]-$v[0])."\n";}}
```

Comment: 73 bytes, PHP4: `$R=str_repeat;foreach($G as$v)echo$R(' ',$v[0]),$R('-',$v[1]-$v[0]),'\n';` (replace the `\n` with a **real** newline). For this to work, you need to send an array on the key `$G`, over POST/GET/SESSION/COOKIE...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel According to the question, the input needs to come as an argument or from STDIN.

Comment: Does `GET` parameters count? And I think that `GET`uses STDIN.

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 112*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int a(){int a,b;while(cin>>a>>b){cout<<string(a,' ')+string(b-a,'-')+"\n";}}
```

*~~or 76 depending on whether you count the include statements~~ just completely wrong... Didn't include std:: as pointed out in comments

#### Test

**Input:** `5 20 5 20 2 10 15 19`

**Output:**

```
     ---------------
     ---------------
  --------
               ----
```

Comment: Don't you need include files for this?

Comment: Yes iostream and string... Should I add those to my code?

Comment: I only started participating here relatively recently, so I'm not much of a rules expert. But it was my understanding that even if only a function is required, you still need to count everything needed to compile the function. You may want to ask one of the "authorities".

Comment: I'll just put it in

Comment: Your input method of space separated values is just fine. And it's my understanding (though I'm often wrong so take it with a grain of salt) that you don't need the `#include`s for functions, but I'll defer that to someone else.

Comment: Thanks re input.  I think the way it is now is pretty safe as far as the byte count goes

Comment: Don't you need `std::` before `string`?

Comment: @sergiol yeah I think you're right

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 89 characters (function body)

```
function gantt($x){array_walk($x,function($a){echo str_pad(str_repeat('-',$a[1]-$a[0]),$a[1],' ',0)."\n";});}
```

I was going to go for reading strings, but as a lot of the entries were taking arrays of integer pairs, I figured I would follow suit for the sake of brevity.

For each tuple `$a` in array `$x` I echo a string of dashes repeated `$a[1] - $a[0]` times, padded up to the larger number `$a[1]` with spaces. Then the obligatory newline.

Comment: You can make your function name just a single letter to save a few bytes. or better yet, if PHP supports anonymous functions, just omit a function name altogether.

Comment: Oh I see now what you mean by "function body." You have to count the entire function definition in your score, not just the innards.

Comment: `printf()` seems shorter than `echo`+`str_pad()`: `function gantt($x){array_map(function($a){printf("%$a[1]s␊",str_repeat('-',$a[1]-$a[0]));},$x);}` (The ␊ in the code is for a literal newline: just wrap your code there.)

Comment: Actually a good old `foreach` is better: `function g($x){foreach($x as$a)printf("%$a[1]s␊",str_repeat('-',$a[1]-$a[0]));}` And this is 79 characters including everything.

Comment: @AlexA. ah, I've seen golfs where people count or discount function headers. I wasn't sure what to go for, hence why I specified what count was what.

Comment: @manatwork Good suggestion! I was going to ask why you didn't use that as an answer, but I saw your Ruby submission. Thanks. I'll edit my submission when I get a chance and be sure to credit you.

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/): 47 characters

```
<D>-\><D><y>=@left{$1;}@repeat{@sub{$2;$1};-}\n
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<D>-\><D><y>=@left{$1;}@repeat{@sub{$2;$1};-}\n' <<< '0->7,5->6,3->6'
-------
     -
   ---
```

Answer (score 0):

## PostgreSQL: 160 characters

```postgresql
create function g(int[])returns text as
$$select string_agg(lpad(repeat('-',$1[x][2]-$1[x][1]),$1[x][2]),chr(10))from generate_subscripts($1,1)x$$
language sql;
```

Sample run:

```
manatwork=# create function g(int[])returns text as
manatwork-# $$select string_agg(lpad(repeat('-',$1[x][2]-$1[x][1]),$1[x][2]),chr(10))from generate_subscripts($1,1)x$$
manatwork-# language sql;
CREATE FUNCTION

manatwork=# select g(array[[0,7],[5,6],[3,6]]);
-------
     -
   ---
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 21 bytes

```
(' -'#~{.,-~/)"1 ::''
```

### ungolfed

```
(' -' #~ {. , -~/)"1 ::''
```

This is essentially just J's copy verb `#`, but its we're copying the space character head of list `{.` number of times, and the hyphen character "2nd list element minus 1st list element" number of times: `-~/`.  Sadly this forces us to have to specify the rank `"1` explictly, and we need to use Adverse `::` to handle the empty case.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYvBCsIwAEPv/YrHFOJkrW21EwueBE@e/AVxDC9@gLBfr8Wxo4EEQl5epXEaOGdEhydXW8flfruWjbBaTR/X2WnXNoGcpdIa83yMbwb2RNaVP5Loa@vnQdtFWsjDj0xEP0ckeEIinP5eJFO@)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, <s>14</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

If the character used for the timeline can be anything we want then one byte can be saved replacing `-<space>` with `Ê`, which will use `l` instead of dashes.

```
®Ìç- hZÎî
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rsznLSBoWs7u&input=W1s1LDIwXSxbNSwyMF0sWzIsMTBdLFsxNSwxOV1dCi1S)

---

### Explanation

```
®             :Map over each sub-array Z
 Ì            :  Get the last element of Z
  ç-          :  Repeat "-" that many times
     h        :  Set the characters starting at index 0 to
      ZÎ      :    Get the first element of Z
        î     :    Repeat <space> that many times
              :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with `-054naF/->/ -M5.010`, 24 bytes

```perl
say"-"x$F[1]."\x0d".$"x"@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJJV6lCxS3aMFZPKabCIEVJT0WpQsnBTen/f1NdOyMDHQhppGtnaKBjCOQYWv7LLyjJzM8r/q9rYGqSl@imr2un/1/X11TPwNAAAA)

Only works in terminal because of the use of `"\x0d"` to overwrite the `-`s with s, but [here's a cast of the script in action](https://asciinema.org/a/6yewapFHPWgDazpA57ZSe8a2w).

To recreate the script, use the below hexdump:

```perl
00000000: 7361 7922 2d22 7824 465b 315d 2e22 0d22  say"-"x$F[1]."."
00000010: 2e24 2278 2240 4622                      .$"x"@F"
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBA, 75 bytes

A declared routine, `f(a)`, which takes input as an array of arrays, and outputs to the console.

```vb
Sub f(a)
For Each t In a
Debug.?Spc(t(0));String(t(1)-t(0),45)
Next
End Sub
```

#### Example I/O

```vb
f Array(Array(28,35),Array(34,40),Array(39,44))
                            -------
                                  ------
                                       -----
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
ε`sDð×?-'-×,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3NaEYpfDGw5Pt9dV1z08Xef//@hoUx0jg1gdGGWkYwiiDE11DC1jYwE)

Takes input in the form `[[5,20],[5,20],[2,10],[15,19]]`.

Explanation:

```
ε`sDð×?-'-×,    IMPLICITLY INPUT ARRAY OF ARRAYS
ε               For each array [a, b] in input:
 `sD                Push stack b, a, a (a on top)
    ð               Push space to stack : [b, a, a, ' ']
     ×?             Print a spaces without newline, stack: [b, a]
       -'-×,        Print (b - a) dashes with newline, stack empty
                Implicit end of loop
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 74 bytes

```
proc G L {lmap s\ e $L {puts [format %$e\s [string repe - [expr $e-$s]]]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc2xCsMgAATQ3a@4wY4BEzVtviBLh@6JQ0htEZIoaqEgfruV0OXg3XAX160U5@2KEXekbV8cwgwNWuU@MWB6Wb8vEReq56oQvTne8NppNJj013lQ3dCglMq5nAMOiaRMEsMVEj04@iqJjuGMDi1DK9EOte5u4BJcQDDwAUJkkv/XD@2NfU7mWD2MIiOoy@UH)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 76 bytes

```
proc G L {lmap s\ e $L {puts [format %$e\s [string repeat - [expr $e-$s]]]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xCsMgAEV3T/EHOwZM1LQ5QZYO3ROHkNoiJFHUQkE8u5XQ5cN7w/tx3Upx3q4YcUfa9sUhzNCgldwnBkwv6/cl4kL1XClEb443vHa6ygaT/joPqhsalFI5lzPhkEjKJDFcIdGDo68k0TGc06FlaCXaoeruBi7BBQQDHyBEJvl//tDe2OdkjtXDKDKCulx@)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 82 bytes

```
proc G L {lmap s\ e $L {puts [string repeat \  $s][string repeat - [expr $e-$s]]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xCoMwAET3fMUbXIVooq1f4NKhuzqIDUWwGmIKBcm3p0E6dTl47@A4Py0xWrdNtNw4ltdo2XsMWSL79jvd7t28PnHGmtHTQ7YPfzKnMx/ryEyeyiGEeA5ZDnEEcUguVNQo6kQVpeSMkkJSVBRN0uUVVaE0WqIatA4i/C7cjZu3Rzevk2MeREtmQ/wC)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 28 bytes

```perl6
*.map: (' ','-'Zx*).join.say
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@19LLzexwEpBQ11BXUddVz2qQktTLys/M0@vOLHyvzWXWqqGho2Bgrmdjo2pghmQNAaSmpr/AQ)

Input is a list of 2-element lists:

```perl6
(<0 7>,<5 6>,<3 6>)
```

Essentially we are using the `'b' x 3 = 'bbb'` operator `x` between the lists `' ', '-'` and `*` (the line input as a list), zipped via `Z`, hence the combined operator `Zx`.

In p6 golfing this seems... suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 75 bytes

```
m00*-8m+1-=+1*01+*-8-*0s0s+1-=*00+*0-1-9 32s1d0d+1-=*1 1+*1-1-9 45d1-9 10m1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hco7CsAwDIPhq2S2MUh9QDv0MAVnNB18f9wkk/g/FF/0eKsCELtCaY9SQB1lgkROEkAFRrvbviUdvpRt/Lj4OH0OEawy/g)

Ungolfed:

```
main 0
0    *-8      # read user input
main +1-=+1*0 # terminate if zero

    1     +*-8-*0 # calculate number of '-' to print

    space 0
    space +1-=*0  # stop?
        0  +*0-1      # decrement counter
        -9 32         # print ' '
    space  1      # go back to start
    dash  0
    dash  +1-=*1  # stop?
        1  +*1-1      # decrement counter
        -9 45         # print '-'
    dash  1

    -9 10

main 1        # go to beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
｛┤∔α ×Ｐ-×ｐ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjVCJXUyNTI0JXUyMjE0JXUwM0IxJTIwJUQ3JXVGRjMwLSVENyV1RkY1MA__,i=JTVCJTVCNSUyQzIwJTVEJTJDJTVCNSUyQzIwJTVEJTJDJTVCMiUyQzEwJTVEJTJDJTVCMTUlMkMxOSU1RCU1RA__,v=6)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÇÉ⌐öç♦}k
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8090a99487047d6b&i=%5B%5D%0A%5B%5B0+7%5D+%5B5+6%5D+%5B3+6%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B5+20%5D+%5B5+20%5D+%5B2+10%5D+%5B5+19%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B28+35%5D+%5B34+40%5D+%5B39+44%5D%5D&m=2)

### Explanation

```
mzsE|r'-&
m         map each pair and print with newline
 z        empty string
  s       swap with pair
   E|r    convert to range
      '-  - character
        & assign at indices(extends the empty string with spaces)
```