# Print the Flag of the Arab Revolt!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

It seems flags are a trend now, so what better place to start an account? I thought bars could use a twist to them, so I found this flag.

Produce the following in the console output the fewest possible bytes:

```
+----------------------------------+
|XXXXX                             |
|XXXXXXXX                          |
|XXXXXXXXX-------------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXX                       |
|XXXXXXXXXXX                       |
|XXXXXXXXX-------------------------+
|XXXXXXXX                          |
|XXXXX                             |
+----------------------------------+
```

This crude rendition of the flag is 36 x 10 characters. A trailing newline on the last line is optional. You may use any language you choose. If it is an obscure language, please post a link to the language in your answer.

Comment: I am not a fan of the arbitrary "The answer must have fewer bytes than this flag..." as it discourages some really neat languages. They won't win anyway, so let them have their fun :)

Comment: You have a point. Editing!

Comment: Why did you accept an answer after 1 hour? That's way too short, IMHO. You should give people some time to submit answers before you pick a winner.

Comment: I guess. I'm new here, so I don't know what to expect.

Comment: It seems that every successive flag question has approximately half the votes of the previous one. If this keeps up, we should soon have a question with 1/1024 of a vote.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/R7bK9rc.png

Comment: @steveverrill Actually, it has more than half, it's just that many votes are -1, rather than +1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## CJam, 44 bytes

```
8T5@9B]_W%+{I'|'+?'XI*34"-  "I=e]"+||"I=N}fI
```

*(Thanks to @Dennis, @Jakube  and @Optimizer for -1 byte each)*

```
8T5@9B]        Push [0 5 8 9 11]
_W%+           Add its reverse, to give [0 5 8 9 11 11 9 8 5 0]
{...}fI        For each I in the above array...
  I'|'+?         Push "+" if I == 0 else "|"
  'XI*             Push I "X"s
  34"-  "I=e]      Pad the "X"s to length 34 with "-" if I%3 == 0 else " "
  "+||"I=          Push "+" if I%3 == 0 else "|"
  N                Push a newline
```

Comment: `"|+"I!=` -> `I'|'+?` . And something similar for the `"-  "I=` and `"+||"I=` too

Answer (score 14):

## SQL (PostgreSQL flavour), <s>284</s> <s>244</s> <s>232</s> <s>210</s> 175 bytes

A HUGE Thank You to @manatwork for essentially the whole thing now.

A nice verbose language that still came in under the byte size of the flag, with a bit of a margin :)

Basically builds the half of the flag with using parameters.  This is cross joined with 1 and -1 giving us both halfs of the flag and a means to order it by negating the number of #'s in the row.

```sql
SELECT rpad(rpad(L,X,'X'),35,P)||R FROM(VALUES('|',12,' ','|'),('|',10,'-','+'),('|',9,' ','|'),('|',6,' ','|'),('+',1,'-','+'))F(L,X,P,R),(values(-1),(1))G(O)ORDER BY(12-X)*O
```

Formatted and commented

```sql
SELECT rpad(rpad(L,X,'X'),35,P)||R --Build each row from parameters
FROM(VALUES           -- Parameters for each row
    ('|',12,' ','|'), -- Start Char, Num of #, Pad Char, End Char
    ('|',10,'-','+'),
    ('|',9,' ','|'),
    ('|',6,' ','|'),
    ('+',1,'-','+')
    )F(L,X,P,R),
    (values(-1),(1))G(O) -- Cross join with order modifier
ORDER BY(12-X)*O -- Order by modified number of #
```

Comment: Change those `'|XXXXX'||repeat(' ',29)` into `rpad('|XXXXX',35)` to reduce it to 263 characters.

Comment: By the way, the sub-`select` is pointless, just the parenthesis does it: `SELECT S FROM F UNION ALL(SELECT S FROM F ORDER BY I DESC)` to reduce it to 250 characters. (At least in 9.4.4.)

Comment: @manatwork Thanks for the tips.  Worked out really nicely.

Comment: The I field is not necessary, as the strings that compose the flag are already in ascending order. Getting rid of that auxiliary field has the benefit of not needing the aliases anymore. And as `asc` is ``shorter than `desc`, you can squeeze one more characters by declaring the flag in reverse order, then reverse the top half using the shorter keyword: `WITH F AS(SELECT*FROM(VALUES(rpad('|XXXXXXXXXXX',35)||'|'),(rpad('|XXXXXXXXX',35,'-')||'+'),(rpad('|XXXXXXXX',35)||'|'),(rpad('|XXXXX',35)||'|'),(rpad('+',35,'-')||'+'))F)(SELECT*FROM F ORDER BY 1ASC)UNION ALL SELECT*FROM F`

Comment: @manatwork Unfortunately the row starting with '+' gets ordered into the wrong position.  Otherwise that would have worked a treat.  I could have also dropped the `ASC`.  But I have adapted your suggestion to get a few more bytes.

Comment: Sadly that may depend on the used collation. :( But given that “+” (code 43) occurs before “|” (code 124) in the [ASCII table](http://asciitable.com/), it works for me. And on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/1639/0) too. Anyway, in meantime I found another solution which involves your original order field but gets rid of CTE  and `union`: `SELECT S FROM(VALUES(1,rpad('|XXXXXXXXXXX',35)||'|'),(2,rpad('|XXXXXXXXX',35,'-')||'+'),(3,rpad('|XXXXXXXX',35)||'|'),(4,rpad('|XXXXX',35)||'|'),(5,rpad('+',35,'-')||'+'))F(I,S),(values(-1),(1))G(P)ORDER BY I*P`

Comment: @manatwork oh very nice

Comment: The 5 separate formatting is still too long. Better use a single formatting based on **L**eft char, **X** count, **P**ad char and **R**ight char. And while the X count will be an increasing integer, it can replace the I field in a modified `order by` formula: `SELECT rpad(rpad(L,X,'X'),35,P)||R FROM(VALUES('|',12,' ','|'),('|',10,'-','+'),('|',9,' ','|'),('|',6,' ','|'),('+',1,'-','+'))F(L,X,P,R),(values(-1),(1))G(O)ORDER BY(12-X)*O`

Comment: @manatwork  You should post that yourself.  It's way different to where I started and really quite impressive golfing.  Sub 200 with SQL.  I was happy with sub 300:)

Comment: Such answer would start anyway with a disclaimer “inspired by MickyT, if you like the base idea, please upvote his answer”. What I suggested is not much different than what you currently have. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```
8U5@9B]34X$f-]z87Zb"X ||X-++X-+|"4/f=..*1fm>_W%+N*
```

*Thanks to @Sp3000 for golfing off 1 byte!*

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=8U5%409B%5D34X%24f-%5Dz87Zb%22X%20%7C%7CX-%2B%2BX-%2B%7C%224%2Ff%3D..*1fm%3E_W%25%2BN*).

#### How it works

```
8U5@9B] e# Push [0 5 8 9 11] (`@` rotates on top).
34X$f-  e# Subtract each integer from 34.
]z      e# Wrap and zip. This pushes [[0 34] [5 29] [8 26] [9 25] [11 23]].
87Zb    e# Push [1 0 0 2 0] (87 in base 3).

"X ||X-++X-+|"4/

        e# Push ["X ||" "X-++" "X-+|"].

f=      e# Select for each. This pushes ["X-++" "X ||" "X ||" "X-+|" "X ||"].

..*     e# Twofold vectorized repetition.
        e# EXAMPLE: [9 25]"X-+|".* -> "XXXXXXXXX-------------------------+|"

1fm>    e# Rotate each string one character to the right.  
_W%     e# Copy the resulting array and reverse the order of its lines.
+N*     e# Concatenate and join by linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 8):

### Python 2, 80

```python
for n in 0,5,8,9,11,11,9,8,5,0:print'|+'[n<1]+'X'*n+'-  '[n%3]*(34-n)+'+||'[n%3]
```

Instead of iterating over the row numbers, iterate over the number of `X`-symbols directly. The stripes happen where `n` is `0` or `9`, which are the only multiples of 3, and so can be checked by the value `n%3` (thanks Sp3000).

This can surely be shortened in Python 3 by converting the list of numbers to a bytes object.

Comment: I was all proud of [mine](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#n%2Cb%3D0%2C%5B%27%2B%27%5D%2B%5B%27%7C%27%2B%27X%27%2aa%20for%20a%20in%205%2C8%2C9%2C11%5D%0Ab%2B%3Db%5B%3A%3A-1%5D%0Afor%20l%20in%20b%3Aprint%20l.ljust%2835%2C%27-%20%20%27%5Bn%253%5D%29%2B%27%2B%7C%7C%27%5Bn%253%5D%3Bn%2B%3D1), and yours is just the same except better :P

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>147</s> <s>132</s>  <s>127</s>  <s>111</s> 106 bytes

```js
[0,5,8,9,11,11,9,8,5,0].map(v=>console.log('|+'[+!v]+'X'.repeat(v)+' -'[z=+!(v%3)].repeat(36-v)+'|+'[z]))
```

#### Demo

As it is ES6, it only works in Firefox at the moment.

```js
// DEMO: redefine console.log to have output inside the snippet
// Taken from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52411/22867
console.log = (...x) => O.innerHTML += x + '\n';

// Actual program
[0,5,8,9,11,11,9,8,5,0].map(v=>console.log('|+'[+!v]+'X'.repeat(v)+' -'[z=+!(v%3)].repeat(36-v)+'|+'[z]))
```

```html
<pre><output id=O></output></pre>
```

Comment: -6: `[0,5,8,9,11,11,9,8,5,0].map(v=>console.log('|+'[+!v]+'X'.repeat(v)+' -'[z=+!(v%9)].repeat(36-v)+'|+'[z]))`

Answer (score 4):

### C, <strike>157</strike> <strike>155</strike> <strike>151</strike> 146 bytes

```
i;f(){for(char b[36];i<10;printf("%c%.34s%c\n",i++%9?124:43,b,i%3?124:43))memset(b,i%3?32:45,34),i%9?memset(b,120,35253>>((i<5?5-i:i)%4*4)&15):0;}
```

edit: I moved the string length inside of the format string and found two bytes.

edit: Added Cool Guy's recommendation and found four bytes.

edit: Removed the array and replaced it with a 4-bit packed short that's shifted to get the 'x' lengths

Comment: I'm having issues compiling this.

Comment: Let me know what error you're receiving and I will see if I can recreate it. I'm compiling using Cygwin GCC 4.8.3 using no compiler flags other than -o.

Comment: @CamelCaseCode This requires C99 or above. BTW, don't care about the warnings...

Comment: @openaddr `for(;i<10;)` --> `for(char b[36];i<10;printf("%c%.34s%c\n",i++%9?124:43,b,i%3?124:43)` saves two bytes. Also, you can remove the `{...}` of the loop and change `;i%9?` to `,i%9?`. +1 anyway. Nice solution!

Comment: @Cool Guy Thanks and good catch on the printf. I was going to put the buffer initializer in the for block, but the compiler complained that declarations within the for header is a C99 feature, so I left it out for maximum compatibility. If the reason CamelCaseCode couldn't compile is indeed because there is some other C99 feature that the compiler missed, then that won't matter anyways since it's already C99 specific.

Comment: Apparently, That does not matter. In code-golf, portability is not required. [And `(int[]){5,11,9,8}` is a C99 feature](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/vac-7.0/html/language/ref/clrc02compound_literals.htm).

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>60</s> <s>54</s> <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 45 bytes

Compared to the previous version, I realized that one of the 5 entries in my descriptors was always the same, which was kind of pointless. Using a fixed value for it:

```
"++-0|| 5|| 8|+-9|| B"4/_W%+{1/~~'X*34@e]\N}/
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%2B%2B-0%7C%7C%205%7C%7C%208%7C%2B-9%7C%7C%20B%224%2F_W%25%2B%7B1%2F~~'X*34%40e%5D%5CN%7D%2F)

*Thanks to @aditsu and @Sp3000 for some related help in chat this morning.*

The basic approach here is that I have 4 character descriptors for the pattern of each line, where the characters in the descriptor are:

- First character.
- Last character.
- Right fill character.
- Repeat count for left fill character.

The left fill character, which was part of the descriptor in earlier versions of this solution, is always `X`, so it is now not part of the descriptor anymore.

These descriptors are specified for the top 5 lines, and repeated for the bottom 5 lines in reverse order.

Explanation:

```
"++-0|| 5|| 8|+-9|| B"
        Descriptors for top 5 lines, as described above.
4/      Split into 5 descriptors of 4 characters each.
_W%     Repeat the 5 descriptors in reverse order.
{       Loop over lines/descriptors.
    1/    Split descriptor string into array with 5 one-character strings.
    ~     Unwrap the array.
    ~     Evaluate last entry in descriptor, which is the count.
    'X    Left fill character.
    *     Repeat left fill character by given count.
    34@e] Pad to 34 characters using right fill character.
    \     Swap last character to top.
    N     Add a newline.
}/    End loop over lines/descriptors.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 282 bytes/characters

```py
f,l,h=lambda a:a in{0,35}and '+'or'-',lambda a:a%3 and'|'or'+',lambda a:a and(a<10 and 'X'or'-')or'|';print("\n".join("".join(x)for x in[[k in{0,9}and f(j)or j==35 and l(k)or k%3 and(j==0 and'|'or j<[0,6,9,0,12,12,0,9,6][k]and'X'or' ')or h(j)for j in range(36)]for k in range(10)]))
```

Output is, of course:

```
+----------------------------------+
|XXXXX                             |
|XXXXXXXX                          |
|XXXXXXXXX-------------------------+
|XXXXXXXXXXX                       |
|XXXXXXXXXXX                       |
|XXXXXXXXX-------------------------+
|XXXXXXXX                          |
|XXXXX                             |
+----------------------------------+
```

I'm sure there's a much shorter way to do this in Python.

Comment: You can use indexing to reduce a fair bit of the `... and ... or ...`, e.g. `"+||"[a%3]`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure the `lambda`s are necessary... I don't think you call them enough times for it to be worth it

Comment: @Sp3000, you're probably right. If I remember to I'll refactor it later.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>156</s> 155 chars

```
h=[5,8,9,11];l=34;t=?++(?-*l)+?+;puts t;2.times{h.each{|c|if c==9 then j='-+' else j=' |';end;print(?|,((?X*c).ljust(l,j[0])),j[1],?\n)};h.reverse!};puts t
```

I used an array, `h`, with the values `[5, 8, 9, 11]`, so I can use `2.times { h.each { code }; h.reverse }` because the flag is symmetrical horizontally. I also use 34 many times in the code, so it is assigned to `l`. `?x` is shorthand for `"x"`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 78

```
"@EHIKKIHE@".each_byte{|i|puts"+|"[i/65]+?X*(i-64)+" -"[i%3]*(98-i)+"|+"[i%3]}
```

A copy of Rinkattendant's / Xnor's idea of iterating over the lengths of the strings of X's. Except instead of using an array, I have compressed them into a string.

## Ruby, 96

Original plain vanilla approach

```
(0..9).each{|i|puts (i%9<1??+:?|)+(?X*("@EHIKKIHE@"[i].ord-64)).ljust(34,"-  "[i%3])+"+||"[i%3]}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
(0..9).each{|i|
   puts (i%9<1??+:?|)                                          #first character + or |
   +(?X*("@EHIKKIHE@"[i].ord-64)).ljust(34,"-  "[i%3])         #print quantity of X's according to string, then right justify with - or space
   +"+||"[i%3]}                                                #last character + or |
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 1.2, 157 bytes

Can be run in a playground, or from a file using `swift file.swift` in Terminal.

```
let z="-----",x="XXX",y="   ",g=y+y,w=z+z+z+z+"----+",e=g+g+g+y+"  |",c="|XX"+x,d=["+"+z+z+w,c+g+e,c+x+y+e,c+x+"X-"+w,c+x+x+e]
print("\n".join(d+reverse(d)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 135 bytes

Lets play around with `printf`:

```php
<?$A='|%-34s|
|%-34s|';$B="|%'--34s|";printf("+%'-34s+
$A
$B
$A
$B
$A
+%'-34s+",'',$a=XXXXX,$b=$a.XXX,$c=$b.X,$d=$b.XX,$d,$c,$b,$a,'');
```

Maybe there are some edges that I've left behind that can be cut.

But it was fun!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 41 bytes

```
»'ꜝ»12τƛ\X*34↲n9=[ð\-V\+|\|]+\|p;\+17-mpm
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%C2%BB%27%EA%9C%9D%C2%BB12%CF%84%C6%9B%5CX*34%E2%86%B2n9%3D%5B%C3%B0%5C-V%5C%2B%7C%5C%7C%5D%2B%5C%7Cp%3B%5C%2B17-mpm&inputs=&header=&footer=)

```
    12τ                                   # Base-12 digits of...
»'ꜝ»                                      # 9119 (so 5,8,9,11)
       ƛ                        ;         # Mapped to...
        \X*                               # That many Xs
           34↲                            # Padded to width of 34
              n9=[         ]              # If it's a 9...             
                  ð\-V\+                  # Replace all spaces with -s and append a +
                        |\|               # Else append a |
                            +\|p          # Prepend a |
                                 \+       # '+'
                                   17-    # Append 17 -s
                                      m   # Mirror the result
                                       p  # Prepend that to the rest
                                        m # Mirror the lot.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sed - 228

```
s/.*/eeeeee\neeeeee/
s/e/------/g
s/^-/+/
s/-$/+/
s/-\n-/+\n+/
s/\n/\nabcddcba/
s/\([a-d]\)/|XXXXX\1\1\1\1\1\1\n/g
s/\([a-d]\)/\1\1\1\1\1/g
s/Xbbb/XXXX/g
s/Xcccc/XXXXX/g
s/Xdddddd/XXXXXXX/g
y/abcd/  - /
s/ \n/|\n/g
s/-\n/+\n/g
q
```

Because of the way sed works, this requires a line of input to output the flag.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 233 bytes

```
putStr$uncurry((.toEnum).replicate)=<<foldl1(++)(((++)=<<reverse)$zipWith zip[[1,11,23,1,1],[1,9,25,1,1],[1,8,26,1,1],[1,5,29,1,1],[1,34,1,1]][[124,88,32,124,10],[124,88,45,43,10],[124,88,32,124,10],[124,88,32,124,10],[43,45,43,10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 558 bytes

```
{iiii}iiicii{ccc}ccccddc{ddd}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}ddddddccccc{dddddd}iiii{cc}ccccccccc{{i}d}iicd{{d}d}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}ddddddcccccccc{dddddd}iiii{cc}cccccc{{i}d}iicd{{d}d}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}ddddddccccccccc{dddd}ddd{cc}ccccc{{i}dd}dcd{{d}d}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}dddddd{c}c{dddddd}iiii{cc}ccc{{i}d}iicd{{d}d}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}dddddd{c}c{dddddd}iiii{cc}ccc{{i}d}iicd{{d}d}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}ddddddccccccccc{dddd}ddd{cc}ccccc{{i}dd}dcd{{d}d}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}ddddddcccccccc{dddddd}iiii{cc}cccccc{{i}d}iicd{{d}d}c{{i}i}ic{ddd}ddddddccccc{dddddd}iiii{cc}ccccccccc{{i}d}iicd{{d}d}c{iii}cii{ccc}ccccddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZJBDoAwCARf5KMMq5Gzxw1vR2iNB2ONTSXhwNJZmhYsM1bdt8mdGmGRokoRsUgBhABMyOiZ1golsl/qlBLmCdVGACkLyCDaDk2THodqkeLFFzykN5xx9mH4l8kD6OClf3q1jp/LxbhthfsB)